Bicep IaC: Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server with private endpoint
I want to create an Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server which uses private endpoint with Bicep.
To do this in the portal i can select Public access (allowed IP addresses) and Private endpoint and deselect Allow public access to this resource through the internet using a public IP address in the networking tab.

But how can i do this in Bicep? I cannot set publicNetworkAccess to Disabled, because then i get the error, that i need to set a value for delegatedSubnetResourceId. So i can create the server with publicNetworkAccess set to Enable and create my private endpoint for the server. But now i cannot change the publicNetworkAccess to Disable because the The property "publicNetworkAccess" is read-only.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.dbforpostgresql/flexibleservers?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

Deploy with publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'

Deploy with publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'  and change to 'Disabled' after first deployment (which deployed private endpoint etc.)



Are you looking for a direct approach with bicep only. @SaibotDev

@Jahnavi Yes. My goal is to build a bicep module for this use case

It is not directly possible to disable the public address and enable it with a private endpoint. @SaibotDev

What exactly do you mean with direct? It is possible using the portal. Which means that it is a bug in ARM/Bicep or not? @Jahnavi

Directly means, first you need to create a server with public address enabled and then create a private endpoint using bicep. Now use either PowerShell or CLI to update the value to disabled. @SaibotDev


Deploy with publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
Deploy with publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled' and change to 'Disabled' after first deployment (which deployed private endpoint etc.)

Firstly, I have deployed a PostgreSQL server with publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled' as shown below.
resource postgresqlServer 'Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers@2023-03-01-preview' = {
  name: 'serverlatest'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_D4ds_v4'
    tier: 'GeneralPurpose'
  }
  properties: {
    version: '13'
    storage: {
      storageSizeGB: 32
    }
    administratorLogin: 'admin'
    administratorLoginPassword: 'xxxx'
    highAvailability: {
      mode: 'Disabled'
    }
    backup: {
      backupRetentionDays: 10
    }
    network: {
      publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    }
  }
}


The command az postgres flexible-server later will be used to update the server configuration with publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled' after the private link deployment is done with bicep.
Refer MS Doc for creating a private endpoint using bicep with the relevant subnets under a virtual network as shown below.
resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-05-01' = {
  name: 'myVnet'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        '10.0.0.0/16'
      ]
    }
  }
}
resource postgresqlServer 'Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers@2023-03-01-preview' existing = {
  name: 'serverlatest'
}
resource subnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2021-05-01' = {
  parent: vnet
  name: 'mySubnet'
  properties: {
    addressPrefix: '10.0.0.0/24'
    privateEndpointNetworkPolicies: 'Disabled'
  }
}
resource privateEndpoint 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints@2023-01-01' = {
  name: 'xxx'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    subnet: {
      id: subnet.id
    }
    privateLinkServiceConnections: [
      {
        name: 'xxx'
        properties: {
          privateLinkServiceId: postgresqlServer.id
          groupIds: [
            'postgresqlServer'
          ]
          requestMessage: 'xxx'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


Output:

